# How to apply style to currently selected option element in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to set `style="color: #D4D4D4"` to specific option elements of `select`. When I set `<option value="TEST" style="color: #D4D4D4">TEST</option>` it successfully changes style when drop down of options is expanded. However the currently selected option element in `select` (when drop down is not expanded) still has default font color. How to change it?

**Update:**

Thanks! But `sel.onchange` is not tracking changes made to attributes of option. I use jQuery to set attribute and need update to be reflected in select immediately. How can I do that?

jQuery

```
$('.form-control option[value="' + $scope.environment + '"]').attr('style', 'color: #D4D4D4');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var sel = document.getElementById("sel");

function changeSelectColor(){
  sel.style.color = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].style.color;
}

changeSelectColor(); // Do when ready
sel.onchange = changeSelectColor; // And do it on change
```

```html
  <select id="sel">
    <option value="TEST1" style="color:red">TEST1</option>
    <option value="TEST2" style="color:blue">TEST2</option>
    <option value="TEST3" style="color:green">TEST3</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score -1):

This code snippet should do the trick

**JQUERY**

```
    $('#dropdownId').change(function(){
        $('#dropdownId').find(":selected").css('color', '#D4D4D4');
        $('#dropdownId').find("option:not(:selected)").css('color', '#000000');
    });
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/Lmda3tfc/