# Cannot execute function using onchange event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I need to track change of color of option element and if one occurs I need to change color of select element. For example I mark inactive environments with `#D4D4D4` color. I  need select element automatically change it's color if inactive environment set. How to do it?

PS. If color applied to select element is ONLY has to be applied to specific elements not whole select if it expanded.

**My currently non-working solution:**

```
$scope.sel = document.getElementById("environment");
    $scope.changeColor = function(){
        $scope.sel.style.color = $scope.sel.options[$scope.sel.selectedIndex].style.color;
    }
    $scope.sel.onchange = $scope.changeColor;

    $("#environment > option").each(function(i, el){
        el.onchange = $scope.changeColor();
    });

    $scope.changeOptionColor = function() {
        $('.form-control option[value="' + $scope.environment + '"]').attr('style', 'color: #D4D4D4');
    }
```

[Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26754180/how-to-apply-style-to-currently-selected-option-element-in-select)

**UPDATE2:**

[image]

As You see two red arrows shows mismatch of colors of the same elements.

**UPDATE3:**

So in a few words what I am trying to accomplish: The color of element pointed by first arrow should ALWAYS match the color of element pointed by second arrow.

Comment: Is this an Angular app?

Comment: Somewhere on SO was the article why you shouldn't use jQuery (in most cases) if you use AngularJS.

Comment: "I need to track change of color of option element and if one occurs I need to change color of select element if it's currently selecte" Am i the only one to just not understand this sentence ?

Comment: @PierreGayvallet he's using his view as the model. If something is a certain color he wants other things to change in response.

Comment: Problem - you're revealing key information in comments to answers below, information that should have been included in your question. Please include contextual code and also let us know where your hands are tied (e.g., options coming from JSP, can't edit them).

Comment: @Shawn Erquhart, LOL, yes I did. That's probabaly why I got downvoted (

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you're trying to use your view as your model (if element looks like this, then change this). Bad approach - your view should always only be a reflection of your model. If the environment is inactive, put that information in your model, and let everything in your view be styled based on that piece of information.

You're also adding styles inline via js.

Here's what I recommend:

1. Figure out what states you're dealing with (inactive, active, etc).
2. Determine how styles should reflect those changes in state, and create class-based css to set those styles (`#environment.inactive {}`, `#environment.active{}`, etc).
3. Create values on your scope (or controller instance) that dictate state, and change those values declaratively from the view via directives (ng-click, etc).
4. Use ng-class to style your view based on the state reflected in the model.

Comment: When the style (color) of option is changed I need to reflect that change by changing color of select element. By default even if option is of different color (when select is expanded), select will still keep displaying it in default color. Is it clear? Do I need to attach screenshots?

Comment: No, but you do need to include more code. What you're doing is extremely backward - if there's a reason you're approaching things this way, it's not in any way clear in your question.

Comment: Maybe it will explain: I must use JSP to generate select and it's options. I can play with AngularJS and jQuery afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using the ng-class directive to dynamically set the class on your element rather than jQuery https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass

```
<div id="environment" ng-class="{{changeColor()}}"/>

$scope.changeColor = function(){
    return someColorClass;
}
```

Comment: Then I have to parse already generated (by JSP) options and bind them somehow to angular variables, maybe array of booleans?